# Flutter: Calling function when clicking outside the TextField

Tags: flutter

I want to call a function when users tap outside the `TextField`, after clicking the textfield to unfocus.

```
return new GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        print('hey');
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: TextField(
          onChanged: (text) {},
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I am trying to use this GestureDetector but it is not working as I would expect. How can I unfocus the textfield by clicking outside of the textfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the whole Scaffold in GestureDetector will do

```
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
      },
      child: Scaffold(...));
```